# This folder: OTHER_FILES - It does not send the folder to DEBUG

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I have a doubt.

I have a file desing for my Qt application

This folder: `OTHER_FILES`, File: `css / css.css`

But when I compile the program does not go to that folder The folder DEBUG. And with that the project does not find the file!

Would anyone know how to fix this?

I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I'm understanding your question, but one way to make sure your "other" files are available is to include them as resources:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/resources.html

Your CSS file would be compiled into your executable, and then you could read it with something like `:/css/css.css`. The documentation explains it all.